# Power shell scripting for IIS Url Rewrite for setting Custom Response Action Status Code

Tags: powershell, iis

I have been working on writing a powershell script on IIS adding Url rewrite Actions. Here is a sample code.

```
$site = "iis:\sites\Sample"
$filterRoot = "system.webServer/rewrite/rules/rule[@name='Redirect www.google.com$_']"
Clear-WebConfiguration -pspath $site -filter $filterRoot

Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'iis:\sites\Sample'  -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/rules" -name "." -value @{name='Redirect www.google.com' ;patternSyntax='Regular Expressions' ;enabled='True' ;}
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath $site -filter "$filterRoot/action" -name "type" -value "CustomResponse"
```

I can set action type to CustomResponse by using this code.But I am unable set Status code to 403 which is a sub property of Action properties.How to set this property using power shell script?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the feature done by adding

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath $site -filter "$filterRoot/action" -name "statuscode" -value 403
```